# MySQL UPDATE TABLE with subquery does not execute subquery first

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I have a query that produces 3 columns (`ApplicationID`, `FamilySize`, `GrantID`).  In the initial query `FamilySize` is a count. The query works, takes about 5 minutes to produce results, and produces expected results.  The query is as such:

```
SELECT t1.ApplicationID, COUNT(*) FamilySize, t1.GrantID
FROM 
(
 SELECT g.ApplicationID, ChildApplicationID `RefID`, g.GrantID
 FROM CONTINUITYCHILD_P `child`
 JOIN uspto.GRANT as g ON child.ApplicationID = g.ApplicationID
 UNION 
 SELECT g2.ApplicationID, ParentApplicationID `RefID`, g2.GrantID
 FROM CONTINUITYPARENT_P `par`
 JOIN uspto.GRANT as g2 ON par.ApplicationID = g2.ApplicationID
) t1
GROUP BY ApplicationID
```

That initial query works fine.  However, I want to use it to update a field in another table Where the `GrantID` match. I'm using MariaDB but looked at the MySQL 8 documentation since MariaDB and MySQL are supposed to have compatible syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

I am trying to use the syntax similar to this:

```
UPDATE t1, t2
SET t1.column = t2.column
WHERE t1.column2 = t2.column2
```

So that would convert my entire initial query into a table (t2) and the table being updated (t1) would be able to match on a column between t1 and t2.

This is the resulting query:

```
UPDATE METRICS_G m,
(
SELECT ApplicationID, COUNT(*) FamilySize, GrantID
FROM 
(
 SELECT g.ApplicationID, ChildApplicationID `RefID`, g.GrantID
 FROM CONTINUITYCHILD_P `child`
 JOIN uspto.GRANT as g ON child.ApplicationID = g.ApplicationID
 UNION 
 SELECT g2.ApplicationID, ParentApplicationID `RefID`, g2.GrantID
 FROM CONTINUITYPARENT_P `par`
 JOIN uspto.GRANT as g2 ON par.ApplicationID = g2.ApplicationID
) t1
GROUP BY ApplicationID

) t2
SET m.FamilySize = t2.FamilySize
WHERE m.GrantID = t2.GrantID;
```

The query gives no errors, and returns in 3ms with 0 rows affected.

This must mean that the sub-query is not being executed since it will normally take a few minutes for that query to return.

What have I done wrong to use the output of a query as a table to match in an UPDATE statement?

Comment: Make a select where you join METRICS_G  and you first select and see if it finds any rows. this result selet you can use to combine the column. but forst ypoui must see if there is any joined rows ar all

Comment: BOoom... You solved it.  METRICS_G was an empty table.  I was using a test table, but it was empty.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the query to the table `METRICS_G` in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE METRICS_G m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ApplicationID, COUNT(*) FamilySize, GrantID
  FROM (
    SELECT g.ApplicationID, ChildApplicationID `RefID`, g.GrantID
    FROM CONTINUITYCHILD_P `child`
    JOIN uspto.GRANT as g ON child.ApplicationID = g.ApplicationID
    UNION 
    SELECT g2.ApplicationID, ParentApplicationID `RefID`, g2.GrantID
    FROM CONTINUITYPARENT_P `par`
    JOIN uspto.GRANT as g2 ON par.ApplicationID = g2.ApplicationID
  ) t1
  GROUP BY ApplicationID
) t2 ON m.GrantID = t2.GrantID
SET m.FamilySize = t2.FamilySize
```

Comment: That's not true according to MySQL 8 documentation.  You can simply include two tables like:  UPDATE t1, t2 and then use a WHERE condition to match them.

Comment: @jonnyjandles `UPDATE t1, t2...` is a multitable update and you use it when you want to update 2 tables. Is this that you want? I don't think so.

Comment: Will it really update both tables?  Why? I only SET t1.column = t2.column.  I didn't set t2.column to anything.

Comment: @jonnyjandles In your case it will not update both tables, especially when the 2nd table is not a table but a non updatable query. What I said in my comment is that the syntax that you use is not appropriate for an UPDATE statement. The correct way to do it is with a join.

Comment: I understand and appreciate your correction on the proper way to do this query!